# How C# SortedList get key by value?

Tags: c#, sortedlist

There is a `SortedList`

```
slLanguage = new SortedList();
slLanguage.Add("Bahasa","id-ID");
slLanguage.Add("Chinese Simplified(中文简体)","zh-CN");
slLanguage.Add("Chinese Traditional(中文繁體)","zh-TW");      
slLanguage.Add("Kazakh","kk-KZ");
slLanguage.Add("Russian(русский)","ru-RU");
slLanguage.Add("Vietnamese(Việt)","vi-VN");
slLanguage.Add("English", "en-US");
```

How can I get the key by value?

For example: Get the item key "zh-CN"

Answer (score 12):

If you would like to get the key from a value, you may use `SortedList.IndexOfValue(object value)` to get the index of the value you specify. Then, use `SortedList.GetKey(int index)` to return a key as `object` from the value's index we just gathered.

**Example**

```
SortedList slLanguage = new SortedList(); //Initializes a new SortedList of name slLanguage
//Add the keys and their values to the list
slLanguage.Add("Bahasa", "id-ID");
slLanguage.Add("Chinese Simplified(中文简体)", "zh-CN");
slLanguage.Add("Chinese Traditional(中文繁體)", "zh-TW");
slLanguage.Add("Kazakh", "kk-KZ");
slLanguage.Add("Russian(русский)", "ru-RU");
slLanguage.Add("Vietnamese(Việt)", "vi-VN");
slLanguage.Add("English", "en-US");
//
object returnedKey = slLanguage.GetKey(slLanguage.IndexOfValue("zh-CN")); //Gets the key from zh-CN as returnedKey of type object
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: This is an irresponsible answer to the question.  The concept of looking up a value from a sorted list is contrary to the design of the data structure.  If it's something that needs to be done much then it's likely that the lookup relationship is reversed, or two lookups (one in each direction) is needed.  Additionally, a SortedList is unlikely the best structure for a lookup; you're almost certainly better off with a Dictionary or a SortedDictionary.

Comment: @Servy Not really sure if I can understand you. Please share your knowledge if you have a better answer. In anyways, I'm really sorry if my answer was not that good. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY A SortedList is honestly not something that should be used much in general; it has highly inefficient adding/removing times, but beyond that, it's also only ever decent at getting the value for a particular key.  It is *not* designed to get the key for a particular value, that will involve a linear search through the data structure.  While this may or may not have performance implications sufficient to be a problem, at the very least it's an indication of poor design; that you're using the wrong data structure or a poorly designed data flow.

Comment: There's a difference between answering a question and solving a problem.  Whenever possible you should do both, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do this, but here's one way to do it:

```
int index = slLanguage.IndexOfValue("zh-CN");
var item = slLanguage.GetKey(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking the key from Value would be not efficient and defeats the purpose of sorted List. Sorted list is really a sorted Dictionary named confusingly as SortedList.